# OV7725 10-bit mode

Tags: sensor, datasheet

I'm trying to get the OV7725 camera sensor to send out 10-bit data instead of 8 bit data but I can't seem to get it work. I have looked in the [datasheet](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0803/9211/files/OV7725.pdf?3787874186050138641) and all I can find about it seems to be in register COM10 (0x15) bit 0 and that one doesn't really affect anything except that the colors get a little fuzzy, and I assume that is because I don't receive the 2 lower bits, when it is set there is no activity on the D1:D0 data pins at all.

Is there something that I'm missing or?

And yes I have the camera working, I just can't seem to find all the registers that would have an impact on the output format mode. I have it set to RGB565 8 bit mode atm.

Comment: can you observe 10 bit data on oscilloscope?

Comment: No, when I set the bit in the register mentioned there is no activity on the D1:D0 pins. 

The camera module has output for D9:D0 where D2 is lsb in 8-bit mode.

Comment: Wh3n COM10 bit 0 is cleared , are you able to see anything for D0 and D1

Comment: No, I can't see any activity on the D1 and D0 pins when the bit is cleared. It's just floating close to 0V.

Comment: So, the data is always only in MSB 8 bits. Time to write to manufacturer.